# How to apply functions in columns for data frames with different sizes in nested list?

Tags: r, nested, plyr

In R, to apply some function to a column, you can do:

```
df$col <- someFunction(df$col)
```

Now my question is, how do you the similar task when you have data frames in a nested list?
Say I have a following list like this, where I have data frames in the second level from the root.

```
                                           +------+------+
                                  type1    | id   | name |
                              +----------->|------|------|
                              |            |      |      |
                              |            |      |      |
                year1         |            +------+------+
           +------------------+
           |                  |
           |                  |            +------+------+-----+
           |                  |  type2     | meta1|meta2 | name|
           |                  +----------> |------|------|-----|
           |                               |      |      |     |
           +                               +------+------+-----+
           |                     type1    +------+------+
           |                  +---------> | id   |name  |
           |                  |           |------|------|
           |     year2        |           |      |      |
   list    +----------------->+           |      |      |
           +                  |           +------+------+
           |                  |  type2     +------+------+-----+
           |                  +--------->  | meta1|meta2 |name |
           |                               |------|------|-----|
           |                               |      |      |     |
           |                    type1      +------+------+-----+
           |                 +---------->  +------+------+
           |                 |             | id   |name  |
           |     year3       |             |------|------|
           +-----------------+             |      |      |
                             |             |      |      |
                             |  type2      +------+------+
                             +---------->  +------+------+-----+
                                           |meta1 | meta2|name |
                                           |------|------|-----|
                                           |      |      |     |
                                           +------+------+-----+
```

And I want to modify the "name" column in each of the data frame in the leaves with some functions and store the results there. How do you do that?

Here is the example data:

```
data<-list()

data$yr2001$type1 <- df_2001_1 <- data.frame(index=1:3,name=c("jack","king","larry"))
data$yr2001$type2 <- df_2001_2 <- data.frame(index=1:5,name=c("man","women","oliver","jack","jill"))
data$yr2002$type1 <- df_2002_1 <- data.frame(index=1:3,name=c("janet","king","larry"))
data$yr2002$type2 <- df_2002_2 <- data.frame(index=1:5,name=c("alboyr","king","larry","rachel","sam"))
data$yr2003$type1 <- df_2003_1 <- data.frame(index=1:3,name=c("dan","jay","zang"))
data$yr2003$type2 <- df_2003_2 <- data.frame(index=1:5,name=c("zang","king","larry","kim","fran"))
```

say I want to uppercase all of the names in in the name column in each data frame stored in the list

Comment: Please post a representative sample of your data.

Comment: My general advice would be to not organize your data this way. It looks to me like what you have here are two (or possibly just one) un-melted data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate (using your simplified example):

```
library(reshape2)
dat1 <- melt(data,id.vars = c("index","name"))
> dat1$NAME <- toupper(dat1$name)
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution, although it doesn't directly answer the question I raised(compared to other solutions using `lapply`, which I upvoted instead) . You were correct in that by organizing the data this way, it resolves all the downstream problems and made the analysis easy. It's as if I asked for a faster horse, and you gave me a car

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @joran's comment above---this is begging to be consolidated by adding type as a column. But here is one way with `rapply`. This assumes that the `name` column is the only `factor` column in each nested data.frame. As in @josilber's answer, my function of choice is `toupper`.

```
rapply(data, function(x) toupper(as.character(x)), classes='factor', how='replace')
```

This will drop the `data.frame` class, but the essential structure is preserved. If your name columns are already `character`, then you would use.

```
rapply(data, toupper, classes='character', how='replace')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can nest the `lapply` function twice to get at the inner data frames. Here, I apply `toupper` to each `name` variable:

```
result <- lapply(data, function(x) {
  lapply(x, function(y) {
    y$name = toupper(y$name)
    return(y)
  })
})
result

# $yr2001
# $yr2001$type1
#   index  name
# 1     1  JACK
# 2     2  KING
# 3     3 LARRY
# 
# $yr2001$type2
#   index   name
# 1     1    MAN
# 2     2  WOMEN
# 3     3 OLIVER
# 4     4   JACK
# 5     5   JILL
# 
# 
# $yr2002
# $yr2002$type1
#   index  name
# 1     1 JANET
# 2     2  KING
# 3     3 LARRY
# 
# $yr2002$type2
#   index   name
# 1     1 ALBOYR
# 2     2   KING
# 3     3  LARRY
# 4     4 RACHEL
# 5     5    SAM
# 
# 
# $yr2003
# $yr2003$type1
#   index name
# 1     1  DAN
# 2     2  JAY
# 3     3 ZANG
# 
# $yr2003$type2
#   index  name
# 1     1  ZANG
# 2     2  KING
# 3     3 LARRY
# 4     4   KIM
# 5     5  FRAN
```

Comment: josilber, maybe I'm misinterpreting, but is this really recursive, or just two nested loops?  Also, I hope you don't mind my borrowing `toupper` in my example.

Comment: Thanks -- updated the wording. Of course the `toupper` borrowing is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a truly recursive version based on `lapply` (i.e. will work with deeper nesting) and doesn't make any other assumptions except that the only types of terminal leaves you have are data frames.  Unfortunately `rapply` won't stop the recursion at data.frames so you have to use `lapply` if you want to operate on the data frames (otherwise Matthew's answer is perfect).

```
samp.recur <- function(x) 
  lapply(x, 
    function(y) 
      if(is.data.frame(y)) transform(y, name=toupper(name)) else samp.recur(y))
```

This produces:

```
samp.recur(data)
# $yr2001
# $yr2001$type1
#   index  name
# 1     1  JACK
# 2     2  KING
# 3     3 LARRY

# $yr2001$type2
#   index   name
# 1     1    MAN
# 2     2  WOMEN
# 3     3 OLIVER
# 4     4   JACK
# 5     5   JILL

# etc...
```

Though I do also agree with others you may want to consider re-structuring your data.