# Make a readable list of object or vector object from and nested list

Tags: r, list, nested, praat

I have created many functionss that I would like to apply on a sublists of a list (i.e. nestedlist) .

For example

```
# Getintervalduration
list.dur <- function(x){
  # x is a (non nested...) list
  dur <- x$xmax-x$xmin
  return(dur)
}
```

So I can get to apply this function on :

(1) a simple dataframe in my list

```
list.dur(intrad_02.textgrid$phones)
```

(2) all the dataframes in my list

```
 lapply(intrad_02.textgrid, list.dur)
```

**(3) all the nested list in my main list and dataframes in the list**

```
durations <- lapply(txtgridnames,list.dur)
```

The third example is what I want to succeed in doing automatically.

For now, `txtgridnames` corresponds  more or less to `names(list)` But I had to modify it semiautomatically, because :

R does allow :

```
durations <- lapply(c(firstnestedlist, second.nested.list, etc.),list.dur)
```

But unfortunatly doesn't allow this:

```
 durations <- lapply(names(list.with.nested.lists.inside),list.dur)
```

Which is a problem when the `names(list)` could change or want to be replicated on a different study case.

For the moment so,  my solution (thinkering here) is to write a table with the names without "quote" and with coma as eol, to read this file i just created with the names and then to create an object manually with all the names.

```
write.table(x=names(corpus),file="txtgridnames.txt", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE, eol=",",col.names=FALSE)

txtgridnames <- readLines("txtgridnames.txt")

txtgridnames
```

!Copy Manuyally the output!..and paste it manually such that :

```
txtgridnames<-c(cnf_01_be,cnf_02_ch[...])
```

**How to automatically get R to understand list(names(mainlist)), i.e. how to automatically create this object "txtgridnames" ?**

---

Here is an example of the datastructure I am dealing with to be clear : (about 502 dataframes in 24 sublists in a main list that constitute my corpus)

A former post also describes the kind of data I am dealing with more precisely (to know what xmin and xmax correspond click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919909/r-dynamic-split-subset-of-dataframe-by-selected-rownumbers-parsing-textgrid-pra)

```
#-------------------------------------------
## Data structure example 
$ cnf_01_be  :List of 17
  ..$ phones        :'data.frame':  2505 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:2505] 0 0.427 0.472 0.512 0.562 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:2505] 0.427 0.472 0.512 0.562 0.632 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:2505] "_" "v" "w" "a" ...
  ..$ syll          :'data.frame':  1146 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:1146] 0 0.427 0.562 0.752 0.952 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:1146] 0.427 0.562 0.752 0.952 1.022 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:1146] "_" "vwa" "la" "do~k" ...
  ..$ delivery      :'data.frame':  1146 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:1146] 0 0.427 0.562 0.752 0.952 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:1146] 0.427 0.562 0.752 0.952 1.022 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:1146] "_" "" "" "" ...
  ..$ link          :'data.frame':  806 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:806] 0 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:806] 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 1.256 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:806] "_" "" "" "l" ...
  ..$ words         :'data.frame':  806 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:806] 0 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:806] 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 1.256 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:806] "_" "voilà" "donc" "vous" ...
  ..$ POS           :'data.frame':  806 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:806] 0 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:806] 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 1.256 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:806] "_" "VER:pres:entatif" "CON:coo" "PRO:sjt" ...
  ..$ discourse     :'data.frame':  750 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:750] 0 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:750] 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 1.256 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:750] "SIL:l" "MD" "CON" "" ...
  ..$ disfluency    :'data.frame':  806 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:806] 0 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:806] 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 1.256 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:806] "SIL:l" "" "" "" ...
  ..$ boundary-dismo:'data.frame':  750 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:750] 0 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:750] 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.082 1.256 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:750] "MAJ" "MAJ" "MINg" "" ...
  ..$ speaker       :'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num 0
  .. ..$ xmax : num 244
  .. ..$ value: chr "1"
  ..$ ortho         :'data.frame':  101 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:101] 0 0.427 3.571 4.3 7.659 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:101] 0.427 3.571 4.3 7.659 8.341 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:101] "_" "voilà donc vous avez bien perçu même intuitivement qu'y avait euh" "_" "des choses issues de radios commerciales ou de radios classiques etcaetera" ...
  ..$ rection       :'data.frame':  117 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:117] 0 0.427 0.752 0.952 7.659 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:117] 0.427 0.752 0.952 7.659 8.341 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:117] "" "md" "md" "urv" ...
  ..$ sequences     :'data.frame':  183 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:183] 0 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.942 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:183] 0.427 0.752 0.952 1.942 2.848 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:183] "" "md" "md" "SV" ...
  ..$ boundary      :'data.frame':  0 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num(0) 
  .. ..$ xmax : num(0) 
  .. ..$ value: chr(0) 
  ..$ contours      :'data.frame':  1143 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:1143] 0 0.427 0.562 0.752 0.952 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:1143] 0.427 0.562 0.752 0.952 1.022 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:1143] "" "" "C" "" ...
  ..$ bdu-auto      :'data.frame':  53 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:53] 0 0.427 7.659 8.341 18.861 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:53] 0.427 7.659 8.341 18.861 19.624 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:53] "" "bdu-1-c_C" "" "bdu-2-s_C" ...
  ..$ EPG           :'data.frame':  54 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:54] 0 0.427 0.952 8.341 8.806 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:54] 0.427 0.952 8.341 8.806 19.624 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:54] "" "PGC-R" "" "PGC-R" ...
 $ cnf_02_ch  :List of 17
  ..$ phones        :'data.frame':  2304 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:2304] 0 0.001 0.219 0.866 0.886 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:2304] 0.001 0.219 0.866 0.886 0.944 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:2304] "_" "n" "y" "m" ...
  ..$ syll          :'data.frame':  1080 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:1080] 0 0.001 0.866 1 1.089 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:1080] 0.001 0.866 1 1.089 1.239 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:1080] "_" "na~" "m9~t" "" ...
  ..$ delivery      :'data.frame':  1080 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:1080] 0 0.001 0.866 1 1.089 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:1080] 0.001 0.866 1 1.089 1.239 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:1080] "_" "" "" "" ...
  ..$ words         :'data.frame':  784 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:784] 0 0.219 0.866 1.089 1.239 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:784] 0.219 0.866 1.089 1.239 1.691 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:784] "_" "humains" "maintenant" "la" ...
  ..$ link          :'data.frame':  784 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:784] 0 0.219 0.866 1.089 1.239 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:784] 0.219 0.866 1.089 1.239 1.691 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:784] "_" "" "" "" ...
  ..$ POS           :'data.frame':  784 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:784] 0 0.219 0.866 1.089 1.239 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:784] 0.219 0.866 1.089 1.239 1.691 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:784] "_" "ADJ:adj" "ADV:adv" "DET:def" ...
  ..$ disfluency    :'data.frame':  785 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:785] 0 0.219 0.866 1.089 1.239 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:785] 0.219 0.866 1.089 1.239 1.691 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:785] "SIL:l" "" "" "CORR-B" ...
  ..$ discourse     :'data.frame':  728 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ xmin : num [1:728] 0 0.219 0.866 1.089 1.239 ...
  .. ..$ xmax : num [1:728] 0.219 0.866 1.089 1.239 1.691 ...
  .. ..$ value: chr [1:728] "SIL:l" "" "" "" ...
  ..$ boundary-dismo:'data.frame':  728 obs. of  3 variables:
[...]
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is there a reason, why you can't use nested lapply calls? `lapply(yourdata, function(x) lapply(x, list.dur))`

Comment: __This is a usefull response__ No. Apart from the fact that I am probably very tired and that I should have think about that earlier, there is no reason to not do this. Thanks a lot. This avoid to modify all my functions or to reshape my data !).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list structure is somewhat regular, which it seems to be, you can use `melt` and then any of the standard "split/apply/combine" style tools (we use `data.table` here).  Also, I modified the function I'm applying to be the sum of `xmin-xmax` so that the output is nice and brief:

```
library(data.table)  
library(reshape2)     # for `melt`
dt.mlt <- data.table(melt(my.list, id.vars=c("xmin", "xmax", "value")))
dt.mlt[, list(sum.duratin=sum(xmax - xmin)), by=list(L1, L2)]
```

Which produces:

```
          L1        L2 sum.duratin
 1: cnf_01ch    phones -1.36252011
 2: cnf_01ch     words  0.21568715
 3: cnf_01ch       POS -0.40070784
 4: cnf_01ch discourse -1.02992545
 5: cnf_01ch      link  1.50889336
 6: cnf_01be    phones -0.34931685
 7: cnf_01be     words -0.27385093
 8: cnf_01be       POS  0.70835139
 9: cnf_01be discourse  0.84285652
10: cnf_01be      link -2.76651670
11: cnf_01fr    phones  0.02533455
12: cnf_01fr     words  3.25470332
13: cnf_01fr       POS  0.97342401
14: cnf_01fr discourse -1.00580501
15: cnf_01fr      link -0.15233178
```

So I've applied a function (or in this case, just `sum(xmax - xmin)`) to every data frame in my nested list `my.list` and output the result as a data frame where the first two columns indicate which data frame the statistic comes from.  Here is the data I used (a two deep nested list):

```
col.names <- c("phones", "words", "POS", "discourse", "link")
my.list <- 
  setNames(
    replicate(
      3, 
      setNames(
        replicate(5, data.frame(xmin=runif(10), xmax=runif(10), value=runif(10)), s=F), 
        col.names
      ),
      s=F
    ),
    paste0(c("cnf_01"), c("ch", "be", "fr"))
  )
```

Note, I stole this from a fairly recent answer by **[Joran to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000025/how-to-apply-functions-in-columns-for-data-frames-with-different-sizes-in-nested/22000833#22000833)**.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion : **If you have nested List, make nested lapply ! _**

```
lapply(yourdata, function(x) lapply(x, list.dur))
```